# Updating Field given in request in java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I  have a table mytable(a int ,b int ,c varchar).
User can send requests

```
PUT  myapi/mytable/{id}
Request body : {'a':1}

PUT  myapi/mytable/{id}
Request body : {'b':2}

PUT  myapi/mytable/{id}
Request body : {'c':"hello"}
```

How can I write this single generic update API which updates field specified in request with associated value for the given 'id', I tried of receiving the object and picked nonnull field to update, is there any better way?

Comment: i think receiving objects and picked nonNull field is a terrible idea. cause with primitive types it wont works. cause they willl have a default values.

Comment: A remark on PUT: as per [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4), put should not be used for partial updates (you can ignore this comment if it is not applicable in your case, but your example suggests partial updates).

Comment: @Hamza Yes im handling that by making wrapper objects like ,, ill use class Mytable{Integer a; Integer b; String c;}

Comment: @SANTHOSKUMAR pls let me know if u find a better way.

Comment: You can use moddelmapper with not null setting

Comment: @User - Upvote don't say Thanks  I want to update not overwrite, can you please elaborate your comment.

Comment: @SANTHOSKUMAR I added a solution

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the Apache `BeanUtils` to copy your POJO's values to your entity:

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(entity, myTable, getNullPropertyNames(entity));

public static String[] getNullPropertyNames (Object source) {
    final BeanWrapper src = new BeanWrapperImpl(source);
    java.beans.PropertyDescriptor[] pds = src.getPropertyDescriptors();

    Set<String> emptyNames = new HashSet<String>();
    for(java.beans.PropertyDescriptor pd : pds) {
        Object srcValue = src.getPropertyValue(pd.getName());
        if (srcValue == null) emptyNames.add(pd.getName());
    }
    String[] result = new String[emptyNames.size()];
    return emptyNames.toArray(result);
}
```

The `copyProperties` method accepts a third argument as properties' names to ommit.

Comment: This will make fields of myTable to NULL except the field given in response

Comment: @SANTHOSKUMAR Right, I've added a fix to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ModelMapper` to map your not null only map into entity.

```
  public static <T> void merge(T source, T target) {
      ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
      modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT).setSkipNullEnabled(true);
      modelMapper.map(source, target);
  }
```

Comment: this doesnt give intended answer https://onlinegdb.com/ByJRnfyMv

Comment: @SANTHOSKUMAR You are using class rather do `modelMapper.map(e,f)` and you don't need to set in `f` https://onlinegdb.com/H1hDDEgGv